# Lenovo z50-70 "dust removal" (reverse fan) on Energy Manager with Ubuntu?

Tags: power-management, lenovo, fan

I have a Lenovo z50-70 and under Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 I had the "Lenovo Energy Manager" software with a "dust removal" function, that basically made the fan turns backwards to shoot the dust away.

Now I installed Ubuntu (Mate 16.04) and I don't find a way to make a similar thing. I can't install Lenovo Energy Manager for Lenovo z50-70 on Wine, and if I install it on Windows 7 Virtual Machine, I can't access to dust removal function.

DO you have a solution?